# Javascript: When should I use function_name.apply ?

Tags: javascript

Many times I see statements like following

```
 Y.CustomApp.superclass.render.apply(this, arguments);
```

I know how apply works. As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

> Calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array.

But then why not call the method directly ?

Comment: I've used this as a reference before: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons you use `apply()` are one or both of:

- You've got the arguments to be passed to the function in the form of an array or array-like object already;
- You want to ensure that `this` is bound in some particular way when the function is invoked.

If you've got a list of values in an array for some reason, and you know that those values are exactly what to pass to the function, what else would you do?  Something like:

```
if (array.length == 1)
  theFunction(array[0]);
else if (array.length == 2)
  theFunction(array[0], array[1]);
else ...
```

clearly is terrible.

If you know that you want `this` to be bound to some object, well you could always make the function a temporary property of the object and call the function via the object, but that's also pretty terrible. If *all* you need to do is bind `this`, and the arguments aren't in an array, well your alternative is to use `.call()` instead of `.apply()`.

Answer (score 2):

You use `apply` when the function is not a method in the object.

Example:

```
var obj = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }

function getName() {
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}

var name = getName.apply(obj);
```